# How can I make large IN clauses more efficient in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

My current query runs very slow when accessing a DB with pretty large tables

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 635433140000000000 AND 635433150000000000
  AND ID IN ('element1', 'element2', 'element3', ... , 'element 3002');
```

As you can see the `IN` clause has several thousand values. This query is executed roughly every second.

Is there another way to write it to improve performance?

Comment: Is there a way the elements can be linked to a field in Table1. By doing that if you put them in a table you can do a simple join. That would up the performance a little.

Comment: Check the execution plan of the query. If a query is slow, you are missing indexes and/or statistics on the underlying table. If the elements come from another table, join to that table instead of trying to create an `in` statement.

Comment: Where do the elements come from? How often do they change?

Comment: Is the `timestamp` column indexed? I assume `id` is indexed already

Comment: Indexes exist on both. Elements come from c# code and change often.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the elements of the IN to an indexed temporary (if the elements change) or permanent table  (if the elements are static) and inner join on them.

Comment: Beat me to it ;). I just wasn't sure if a static table was even an option for the SO.

Comment: This won't help if there are no proper indexes on `timestamp` and `ID`. It may well be that the culprit is an unindexed `timestamp` column instead of a probably indexed `id`

Comment: Not much will, in that case.

Answer (score 4):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 635433140000000000 AND 635433150000000000 AND
      ID IN ('element1', 'element2', 'element3', ... , 'element 3002');
```

The query is fine.  Add an index on `table1(id, timestamp)`.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer depends on how those `element` ID listings are selected, but it all comes down to one thing: getting them into a table somewhere that you can join against. That will help performance tremendously. But again, the real question here is how best to get those items into a table, and that will depend on information not yet included in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your execution plan, I guess you could have a parameter sniffing problem caused by your between. Check if the actual rows are way off you expected values. And you can rewrite your IN to a EXISTS, which works inside like a INNER JOIN.

Comment: The query optimizer is smart enough to create the same execution plan for IN or EXISTS